# Software to queue human interactions and stay focus

Tags: time-management, productivity, communication

I'd like to put some more deep work on my team.

Do you know if there is any small utility to show the rest of the team that I'll be focus until a given time and allow to leave a message ?

I see that like a networked pomodoro timer in the status bar of MacOS with the list of my teammates and their status.

I thought about using the "No disturb mode" from Slack, but it doesn't tell people when I'll be available again and it's not quickely accessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a slack app that may solve the problem. It's called Qdo and it's a Pomodoro and a task queue as well

https://www.qdochat.com/